# What is the best way to restrict size of database in PostgreSQL 13.0?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to restrict the maximum size of my postgreSQL databases.

I have read that there is no build in method (or at least yet), in order to do this, so it would be possible to create a tablespace with size limitation and then create the db there (though, I have also read that it is not necessarily recommended to do this).

I am using PostgreSQL 13.0 (Ubuntu 13.0-1.pgdg18.04+1) running on Ubuntu 18.04.

Are there any other ways?

Comment: No, there is no reliable way to do so (btw: the Postgres team recommends to **always** run the latest minor release, which would be 13.3 - but that is irrelevant for your question, only for the health of your data)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will upgrade to 13.3.

Comment: In my case I have configured the server to have an external volume for saving the files. What if I reach the size limit of that volume? Is there a way to tackle this issue? I do not have that much experience with postgresql, but I am afraid that the server might crash when the volume has no more free disk space...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a tablespace of limited size for each database. There is no problem with that.

Comment: But won't Postgres simply stop as well if the tablespace is full?

Comment: Not unless your `pg_wal` is on that file system. Otherwise, all you will get is an error.

Comment: In case I am using replication, do I need to also replicate the filesystem of the tablespace to the replication VM?

Comment: Not the file system (PostgreSQL doesn't know about that), but the tablespace.